# Techniques for backwards-Leibniz theorem of product of derivative?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, derivatives, soft-question

If I have a function like $$u(t)f'g + w(t) fg'$$ and I know that for general $f,g$: $$(fg)' = f'g + fg'$$

Is there some general way for me to modify the expression so that I can end up with derivative of a product?

---

**Own work:**
$$\frac{\partial }{\partial t}\left\{f(a(t)) \cdot g(b(t))\right\} = a'(t)f'(a(t))\cdot g(b(t)) +f(a(t))\cdot b'(t)g'(b(t))$$

So if I can get $b',a'$ to match $u,w$ then it shall work.

A special case when this works should be "time-flipping" $a(t) = -t$

$$\sin(t) y(t) + \cos(t) y'(t) =/y(-t) = u(t)/= (u(-t)(-\cos(t)))'$$

But this is just a toy example to see that it works for a simple function. I am curious if it always will be possible or at least for some reasonably large family of functions.

Answer (score 1):

One way to obtain such a product will be to multiply and divide through by an *integrating factor* $v:=v(t)$ to obtain
$$ugf’+wg’f=\frac{1}{v}(uvgf’+vwg’f)=\frac{1}{v}(uvfg)’\,,$$ where, for example, $(uvg)’=vwg’$.
It follows that $v’ug+v(ug)’=vwg’$, or equivalently $$\frac{v’}{v}=\frac{wg’-(ug)’}{ug}= \frac{wg’}{ug}-\frac{g’}{g}-\frac{u’}{u}\,.$$ Upon integrating, the sought-after $v$ becomes $$v=\frac{1}{ug}\exp\left(\int\frac{w}{u}d(\ln(g))\right)\,.$$ If this is a less tractable integral, then consider $uvf’=(vwf)’$ and solve for $v$ instead as $$v=\frac{1}{wf}\exp\left(\int\frac{u}{w}d(\ln(f))\right)\,.$$

**Added Later**
In case you’d rather prefer derivative of a product *but without having $v$ as quotient* then you’re looking at a solution of the form $(vfg)’=uf’g+wfg’$, which can/may be solved for $v$ by integrating, though this may be less tractable than the previous approach.

Comment: I don't see how integrating factor helps here. One of the points of the construction would be to avoid it. But thank you for the contribution anyway.